# How do you get into the pro league of legends scene?

Tags: league-of-legends

I recently started a team with my friends and brothers and we are interested in participating in tournaments.

I know about go4lol and the ggchronicle tourneys, but I was wondering what other options there are, too.

Right now we are working on getting highly ranked on the server and asking other people to do clan wars. Pease let me know if you have any other suggestions!

Comment: Sorry, but recommendations are off-topic. See the faq or join us in chat if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much you got to get a face out there. Get a high rank for your team and defeat some of the well known teams. They got up there by standing among the best. Look at the LoL website and see the ranking for the ranked team 5v5 to see what you should be shooting for. However i must say if you have a preplanned team out there you will probably not make it that far I have tried it and there is always sometime holding you down or someone much better.